# Go Gorm model with has many association not migrated to database

Tags: go, one-to-many, go-gorm

I recently working with gorm model and already define struct model like this :

```
type WorkingHour struct {
    ID           uint64    `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;autoIncrement"`
    WorkingDayID uint64    `json:"working_day_id"`
    Start        time.Time `json:"start"`
    End          time.Time `json:"end"`
}

type WorkingDay struct {
    ID          uint64 `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;autoIncrement"`
    VacanciesID uint64 `json:"vacancies_id"`
    Monday      bool   `json:"monday"`
    Tuesday     bool   `json:"tuesday"`
    Wednesday   bool   `json:"wednesday"`
    Thursday    bool   `json:"thursday"`
    Friday      bool   `json:"friday"`
    Saturday    bool   `json:"saturday"`
    Sunday      bool   `json:"sunday"`

    WorkingHours []WorkingHour `json:"working_hours" gorm:"foreignKey:WorkingDayID;references:ID"`
}
```

And using gorm automigrate like this :

```
s.DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(
    &models.Office{},
    &models.WorkingHour{},
    &models.WorkingDay{})
```

Here is the log:

```
    The env values successfully loaded
    Connected to the postgres database
    2021/07/16 15:53:46 ←[31;1mD:/GoProject/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.1.0/migrator.go:157 ←[35;1mERROR: relation "working_days" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)
←[0m←[33m[189.999ms] ←[34;1m[rows:0]←[0m CREATE TABLE "working_hours" ("id" bigserial,"working_day_id" bigint,"start" timestamptz,"end" timestamptz,PRIMARY KEY ("id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_working_days_working_hours" FOREIGN KEY ("working_day_id") REFERENCES "working_days"("id"))
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.

[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
- using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
- using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

[GIN-debug] GET    /images/                  --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetImagesAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /images/:id               --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetImageByIDAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /images/find              --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).FindImagesAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /images/download          --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DownloadImageAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /images/static/*filepath  --> github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*RouterGroup).createStaticHandler.func1 (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] HEAD   /images/static/*filepath  --> github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*RouterGroup).createStaticHandler.func1 (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /images/                  --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).UploadImageAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /images/:id               --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteImageAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /addvertisements/         --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetAddvertisementsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /addvertisements/:id      --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetAddvertisementAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /addvertisements/find     --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).FindAddvertisementAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /addvertisements/         --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).CreateAddvertisementAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /addvertisements/:id      --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteAddvertisementAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /rate_interests/          --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetRateInterestsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /rate_interests/:id       --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetRateInterestAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /rate_interests/find      --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).FindRateInterestsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /rate_interests/          --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).CreateRateInterestAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] PUT    /rate_interests/:id       --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).EditRateInterestAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /rate_interests/:id       --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteRateInterestAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /faqs/                    --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetFAQsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /faqs/:id                 --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetFAQAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /faqs/find                --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).FindFAQsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /faqs/                    --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).CreateFAQAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] PUT    /faqs/:id                 --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).EditFAQAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /faqs/:id                 --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteFAQAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /docs/                    --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetDocumentsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /docs/:id                 --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetDocumentByIDAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /docs/find                --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).FindDocumentsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /docs/download            --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DownloadDocumentAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /docs/                    --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).UploadDocumentAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /docs/:id                 --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteDocumentAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /criticism_suggestions/   --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetCriticismSuggestionsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /criticism_suggestions/:id --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetCriticismSuggestionAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /criticism_suggestions/find --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).FindCriticismSuggestionsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /criticism_suggestions/   --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).CreateCriticismSuggestionAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /criticism_suggestions/:id --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteCriticismSuggestionAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /news/                    --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetNewsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /news/:id                 --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetSingleNewsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /news/find                --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).FindNewsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /news/                    --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).CreateNewsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /news/:id                 --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteNewsAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /news/types/              --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetNewsTypesAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /news/types/:id           --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).GetNewsTypeAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /news/types/              --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).CreateNewsTypeAPI-fm (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] DELETE /news/types/:id           --> github.com/girihanbudi/bprks/backend/api/controllers.(*Server).DeleteNewsTypeAPI-fm (4 handlers)
Listening to port 192.168.75.81:3001
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on 192.168.75.81:3001
```

Other model are successfully created in database except 2 model above. When I comment out WorkingHours in WorkingDay model it migrated well. I using postgres by the way. I following this [gorm documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html) for one to many association but still can't figure out what is missing.

Comment: could you provide an error message you get?

Comment: I already added the log. Thank u

Comment: do you need the references tag since GORM by default uses the owner’s primary key as the foreign key’s value?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solve the problem by changing the hierarchy of automigrate from this

```
s.DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(
    &models.Office{},
    &models.WorkingHour{},
    &models.WorkingDay{})
```

to this

```
s.DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(
    &models.Office{},
    &models.WorkingDay{},
    &models.WorkingHour{}
    )
```